# jQuery TinyMCE advimage Missing

Tags: jquery-plugins, tinymce

advimage is missing from the jQuery package for TinyMCE 4.  I tried to use the one from an older version but that didn't work.  Where can I get the plugin that will work with TinyMCE 4?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. These plugins were for 3.x series of TinyMCE, in 4x series the below mentioned plugins have been removed.

`advhr, advimage, advlink, iespell, inlinepopups, style, emotions and xhtmlxtras`

See this for complete details: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x